# #docusign Unable to 'Select the account ID you want to use to promote the integrator key'

Tags: docusignapi

I am attempting to promote my integrator key to production.  I have reached the step where I am to 'choose the production account'. The pop up says to 'Select the account ID you want to use to promote the integrator key'.  I only have one production account and I have admin access to it.  I can see it in the pop up but it is grayed out and I am unable to select it.  How do I select it so that I can progress past this stage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using a 30-day trial or a freemium account?

> note that certain account types - such as 30-day Free Trials and Freemium accounts - are not eligible for key promotion and will be grayed out in the list of accounts.

Comment: Thank you for your help!! It looks like when I log in through the admin.docusign login page it is not the same account as the account that I log in to through the regular docusign.com login page.  I log in with the same credentials so I didn't realize it was two different accounts.  It turns out I don't have admin privileges for the account I am trying to promote the key to.  --- I can't vote up your answer because I have less than 15 reputation points.